# Specifying cwd with sys.process ProcessBuilder

Tags: scala

`java.lang.ProcessBuilder` allows me to specify the current working directory. I cannot seem to find any equivalent functionality in `scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilder`. Any clues?

Since there is an implicit conversion from the former to the latter, I can do something like this:

```
import java.lang.{ProcessBuilder => JProcessBuilder}
import scala.sys.process._

val cmd = "yo crazy mama".split(' ')
val pb  = new JProcessBuilder(cmd: _*).directory("cwd")
pb.!  // converted
```

But I would prefer to not mix the two builders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for [this API](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.10.x/src/library/scala/sys/process/Process.scala#L80) on `Process` or similar.

```
def apply(command: Seq[String], cwd: Option[File], extraEnv: (String, String)*): ProcessBuilder
```